# Not showing dropdown in async Select when there are no options loaded

Tags: reactjs, select, jsx, reactstrap

I am using an async select from react-select. Currently when I start typing in the select before there is anything returned from the api a dropdown that says No options as it waits for options to load. But I am wondering it is possible to not show the dropdown until there are options to display?

this is my select component:

```
return (
        <AsyncSelect
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, field)}
            isMulti={false}
            backspaceRemovesValue={true}
            placeholder={"Type to Select"}
            className="form-medication-select"
            styles={error ? errorStyles : customStyles}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
            name={field}
            value={selectValue}
        />
    )
```

Comment: Try implementing the attribute defaultOptions.  This is meant for initial loading when the data hasn't been retrieved yet.

Comment: https://react-select.com/async